# Subsonic 3 alpha and Visual Web Developer 2008: problem with t4 templates

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, t4

I use VWD 2008 Express on Windows 7 beta. When I add Subsonic 3 templates to my MVC RC project, Web Developer Express doesn't generate classes based on them. Connection string is correct. Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

That's because T4 templates require Visual Studio Standard edition or higher.

There are some workarounds that some people have been trying out by using the [command line tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126245.aspx) for generating the code, but I haven't seen one that actually works with Subsonic 3. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/786734/subsonic-asp-net-mvc-sample-in-visual-web-developer-express/1009950#1009950) answer for more information.