# MySQL T4 Templates Error: Metadata file 'MySql.Data' could not be found

Tags: mysql, subsonic, subsonic3, t4, vwdexpress

D:\Web\CityV2\App_Code\ActiveRecord.tt(0,0) : error CS0006: Compiling transformation: Metadata file 'MySql.Data' could not be found

Let me start by saying I'm using VWD 2008 Express.

These are the steps I've taken so far:

- Created an entirely new project
- Added references for Subsonic.Core.dll and MySql.Data.dll
- Copied Active Record templates to project
- Changed all <#@ include file="SQLServer.ttinclude" #> to <#@ include file="MySQL.ttinclude" #>
- Copied the MySQL.ttinclude and Settings.ttinclude from the TemplateProviders folder
- Updated Settings.ttinclude with my connectionstring and database information
- Updated the Settings.ttinclude and created the external tool mapping as per [ranomore's instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/786734/subsonic-asp-net-mvc-sample-in-visual-web-developer-express)
- Attempted to build the code from the templates and received the error

I then realized that I didn't have MySql Connector "installed" on my dev box (even though I added a reference to the bin).  So I proceeded to MySQL.com and downloaded the latest 6.0.4 connector msi and installed it (GAC).  The error no longer appears, but neither does anything else: no new classes, no new errors, nothing [and yes, I refreshed the project after running the command ;-)].

Two things:

1. Am I missing a step somewhere?
2. Is there a way build the templates without needing MySQL installed to the GAC?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately SubSonic 3 doesn't support VWD 2008 Express (or more specifically VWD doesn't support t4). There is a sort of workaround that ranomore came up with but it will require some work by you. See the following question for more details:

[SubSonic ASP.NET MVC sample in Visual Web Developer Express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/786734/subsonic-asp-net-mvc-sample-in-visual-web-developer-express)

EDIT: I should have read your question properly you obviously already have the link above. Maybe worth your while downloading the [trial of VS professional](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=83c3a1ec-ed72-4a79-8961-25635db0192b&displaylang=en) and seeing if you have more luck with that to see if it's worth outlaying the cash to buy it. 
On a side note if you're looking to get an msdn subscription for free you should have a look into registering for the [bizspark program](http://www.microsoft.com/bizspark/)