# Opening examples

Tags: subsonic3

Trying to open SubSonic 3.0 examples solution on VS 2k8 Web Express but says cannot be opened. Why? Can you help me?
Thanks!

Comment: Is that all it says or does it give some sort of error message?

Answer (score 0):

SubSonic 3 does not work with VS Express because express does not support t4 templates. See this question:

[SubSonic ASP.NET MVC sample in Visual Web Developer Express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/786734/subsonic-asp-net-mvc-sample-in-visual-web-developer-express)