# Compile error using SubSonic ActiveRecord templates in Visual Web Developer Express

Tags: activerecord, subsonic, subsonic3, t4, vwdexpress

Thanks to [ranomore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/786734/subsonic-asp-net-mvc-sample-in-visual-web-developer-express/1009950#1009950) I was able to get the Subsonic T4 code generation to work in Visual Web Developer Express for my ASP.Net MVC project, however only using the LinqTemplates.

When I use the ActiveRecord templates with the same settings my project does generate files, but the code doesn't compile anymore...

Any ideas?

Comment: I think it's a good idea to include error messages from the compiler ..

Comment: I got 32 errors, but this is the first one:

The type 'ray.testDB' already contains a definition for 'DataProvider' ActiveRecord.cs line 21

Answer (score 1):

Take the other T4 templates out first.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, it seems to be an issue with the project type.

A ordinary ASP.Net Website project does not have any compile errors, but only the new MVC project has problems with it.

So the work around is: creating a Asp.net Website project to generate the code and then dumping the output back in a MVC project. That works for now, but maybe someone could have a look at this at some point... 

Another minor issue I found is that the ActiveRecord.tt converts into a .txt file rather than a .cs file in VWD, while the other templates do convert into .cs files.