# Subsonic 3 work virtual basic .net project

Tags: vb.net, subsonic3

i download subsonic 3 today (subsonic 3 preview 2) but this don't work in vb project !
i think because .tt file (for generation) is C# template so this don't generate vb code !

can you help me ? thanks...

Answer (score 1):

It's visual basic.net (or vb.net) not virtual basic.

The current version is 3.0.0.3 version and can be downloaded at http://subsonicproject.com/Download

You should read through this to see if it answers your T4 questions.

- [SubSonic ASP.NET MVC sample in Visual Web Developer Express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/786734/subsonic-asp-net-mvc-sample-in-visual-web-developer-express)

Here's another link with T4 info

- http://www.hanselman.com/blog/T4TextTemplateTransformationToolkitCodeGenerationBestKeptVisualStudioSecret.aspx