# Subsonic Question, is it possible execute templates during runtime?

Tags: subsonic, subsonic3

Before ask my question, i have to say that subsonic is wonderfull tool, i realy like it.
I have an application which is createg domain layer during the runtime itself. I mean It has got customizable entites and when the entity added or any entity schema changed my model layer compiled again in the runtime according to changed database.

I'm wondering that, is it possible to execute subsonic templates during the runtime or when the user changed enetity schema or add to new entity to the application can it automatically generate the model layer again ? or how to trigger the template during the runtime of Subsonic ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you make some modifications to the templates you can use the TextTransform.exe command line tool to generate SubSonic classes as described in the following answer:

[SubSonic ASP.NET MVC sample in Visual Web Developer Express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/786734/subsonic-asp-net-mvc-sample-in-visual-web-developer-express/1009950#1009950)

You could then automate the execution of the commandline when your user modifies the schema.

Comment: Thank you Adam, It was help me.